# Unexpected Output while retrieving Data from mongodb and displaying in a csv file?

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

**Problem**

I am retrieving data from mongodb and producing output in a text/csv format.
While user Records does not have any value for field interest for a user but still i am getting value for the field interest for the given user.

**MyAnalysis:**

While debugging I got these results which match with my mongodb data but the text/csv data produced is wrong.

```
59e75753a7986c0a86c758ffCOOKING
[COOKING]
59e759c6a7986c0a86c75901READING
[READING]
59e75f0ea7986c0c4b003e24READING
[READING]
59e7926ea7986c0fc809cbd9CRICKET
[CRICKET]
```

> Can anyone guide what I am doing wrong.Thankx in advance.

**Below is the Code I have written**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class ReportController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/endcustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
public void endCustomerReport(HttpServletResponse response) {
    ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter=null;
    int pageSize=2000;
    Page<User> users=null;
    int page=0;
    String csvFileName = "End-customer.csv";
    List<String> headerList=null;
    Field[] declaredFields=null;
    UserReport userReport=new UserReport();
    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", csvFileName));
        headerList = new ArrayList<>();
        declaredFields = UserReport.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field declaredField : declaredFields) {
            headerList.add(declaredField.getName());
        }
        csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(),
                CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        String[] header = headerList.toArray(new String[]{});
        csvWriter.writeHeader(header);
/*   CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE
    Ready to use configuration that should cover 99% of all usages.*/


        do {
            users = userService.getAllUsers(new PageRequest(page,pageSize));
            for (User user : users) {
                List interests=new ArrayList();
                userReport.setName(user.getName());
                userReport.setUsername(user.getUsername());
                userReport.setContact(user.getContact());
                userReport.setAddress(user.getAddress());
                userReport.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                userReport.setConnections(user.getConnections()); //See it's data
                userReport.setPending(user.getPending());//See it's data
                INTERESTS intrests[]=user.getInterests();
                if(intrests!=null) {
                    for (INTERESTS interest : intrests) {
                        System.out.println(user.getId()+""+interest);
                        interests.add(interest);
                    }
                    System.out.println(interests);
                    userReport.setInterests(interests);
                }
                //See it's data
                userReport.setOccupation(user.getOccupation());
                userReport.setGender(user.getGender());
                csvWriter.write(userReport, header);
            }
            page++;
        }while (users.hasNext());
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(csvWriter!=null){
            try {
                csvWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**My user Document**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59e75753a7986c0a86c758ff"), 
"_class" : "com.ideationz.client.models.User", 
"contact" : "9811164864", 
"email" : "jalaj.chawla93@gmail.com", 
"address" : "44HakikatNagar", 
"gender" : "MALE", 
"name" : "jalaj", 
"dob" : ISODate("1993-02-10T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
"username" : "jalaj", 
"country" : "india", 
"designation" : "engineer", 
"imid" : "1", 
"interests" : "COOKING"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59e7583da7986c0a86c75900"), 
"_class" : "com.ideationz.client.models.User", 
"contact" : "9811164865", 
"email" : "jalaj.chawla95@gmail.com", 
"address" : "44HakikatNagar", 
"gender" : "MALE", 
"name" : "jalaj5", 
"dob" : ISODate("1994-02-10T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
"username" : "jalaj5", 
"country" : "india", 
"designation" : "engineer", 
"imid" : "2"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59e759c6a7986c0a86c75901"), 
"_class" : "com.ideationz.client.models.User", 
"contact" : "9811164866", 
"email" : "jalaj.chawla96@gmail.com", 
"address" : "44HakikatNagar", 
"gender" : "MALE", 
"name" : "jalaj6", 
"dob" : ISODate("1994-02-10T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
"username" : "jalaj6", 
"country" : "india", 
"designation" : "engineer", 
"imid" : "3", 
"interests" : "READING"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59e75f0ea7986c0c4b003e24"), 
"_class" : "com.ideationz.client.models.User", 
"interests" : "READING", 
"contact" : "9811164867", 
"email" : "jalaj.chawla97@gmail.com", 
"address" : "44HakikatNagar", 
"gender" : "FEMALE", 
"name" : "jalaj7", 
"dob" : ISODate("1994-02-10T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
"username" : "jalaj7", 
"country" : "india", 
"designation" : "engineer", 
"imid" : "4"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59e7926ea7986c0fc809cbd9"), 
"_class" : "com.ideationz.client.models.User", 
"contact" : "9811164869", 
"email" : "jalaj.chawla99@gmail.com", 
"address" : "44HakikatNagar", 
"gender" : "MALE", 
"name" : "jalaj9", 
"dob" : ISODate("1993-11-13T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
"username" : "jalaj9", 
"country" : "india", 
"designation" : "engineer", 
"imid" : "9", 
"interests" : "CRICKET"
}
```

**Output Expected**

```
name    username    contact     address      email                   connections     pending  interests   occupation    gender  region
jalaj   jalaj   9811164864  44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla93@gmail.com                            [COOKING]               MALE    
jalaj5  jalaj5  9811164865  44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla95@gmail.com                            []                      MALE    //Change here
jalaj6  jalaj6  9811164866  44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla96@gmail.com                            [READING]               MALE    
jalaj7  jalaj7  9811164867  44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla97@gmail.com                            [READING]             FEMALE    
jalaj9  jalaj9  9811164869  44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla99@gmail.com                            [CRICKET]               MALE
```

**Output Shown**

```
name    username  contact   address email   connections pending interests   occupation  gender  region
jalaj   jalaj     9811164864    44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla93@gmail.com            [COOKING]       MALE    
jalaj5  jalaj5    9811164865    44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla95@gmail.com            [COOKING]       MALE    
jalaj6  jalaj6    9811164866    44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla96@gmail.com            [READING]       MALE    
jalaj7  jalaj7    9811164867    44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla97@gmail.com            [READING]       FEMALE  
jalaj9  jalaj9    9811164869    44HakikatNagar  jalaj.chawla99@gmail.com            [CRICKET]       MALE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **value** is retained from the **previous iteration**.

You have to initialize the `userReport` (`UserReport userReport=new UserReport();`) in the for loop or do a `setInterests(null)`.